# RDD doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, pycharm, pyspark

I' m currently working on a project and can't seem to overcome an error in spark.
function like .first() and .collect() won't give results.
this is my code:

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7"

# Append pyspark  to Python Path
sys.path.append("C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python ")

try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf

    print ("Successfully imported Spark Modules")

except ImportError as e:
    print ("Can not import Spark Modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)

import re

sc = SparkContext()
file = sc.textFile('rC:\\essay.txt')

word = file.map(lambda line: re.split(r'[?:\n|\s]\s*', line))

word.first()
```

when i run it on pycharm. It generates the following:

```
Successfully imported Spark Modules

16/12/18 17:23:41 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/12/18 17:23:43 WARN SizeEstimator: Failed to check whether UseCompressedOops is set; assuming yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User1/PycharmProjects/BigData/SparkMatrice.py", line 43, in <module>
    word.first()
  File "C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1328, in first
  File "C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1280, in take
  File "C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2388, in getNumPartitions
  File "C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19.partitions.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: rC:%5Cessay.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.stringToPath(StringUtils.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:411)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$29.apply(SparkContext.scala:992)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$29.apply(SparkContext.scala:992)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: rC:%5Cessay.txt
    at java.net.URI.checkPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
    ... 32 more
```

Same thing happens when i replace .first() with .collect().(same thing happens when i use the terminal instead of pycharm).
I hope that someone can help me figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is listed there for you, your path is wrong:

> Caused by: java.net.**URISyntaxException**: Relative path in absolute URI: **rC:%5Cessay.txt**
>       at java.net.URI.**checkPath**(Unknown Source)

You need to change

```
file = sc.textFile('rC:\\essay.txt')
```

to

```
file = sc.textFile(r'C:\\essay.txt')
```

Comment: Hi Justin Thank you for your answer. I have tried that too and this is what it generates:

Comment: Hi Justin Thank you for your answer. I have tried that too and this is what it generates at the end this instead of any result: 
WARN SizeEstimator: Failed to check whether UseCompressedOops is set; assuming yes

Comment: You need to print the output in some way. You are just getting the value and doing nothing with it

Comment: I think the problem is in the RDD itself. whatever action or transformation i try to apply Spark acts as it doesn't know it.

Comment: What do you have to back that up? Have you tried sc.textFile.first and printed that that works? map doesn't filter, so that shouldn't really make a difference though. Otherwise, you need to provide the output of a print(word.first()) and we can go from there